# Make eval() consider '%' as '/100'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, eval

How can I force eval() to replace `%` by `/100`?
In my app, I'll get dynamic formulas which I need to evaluate. I am evaluating those formulas with eval(). Issue arises when the dynamic formula has `%`. Eg.

`E_LOW%*CT_TOTAL+(1-GQC)`

where E_LOW, E_TOTAL, GQC are constants.

Eg.

> E_LOW = 10

I want E_LOW% to be evaluated as 0.10, i.e. E_LOW% = 10/100 = 0.10

Currently I am getting following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

**Note:** Here issue is not with `*`. Even if I do `eval(E_LOW%)`, I get error as

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

So whatever comes after `%`, eval isn't able to evaluate/understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `%` is an operator. You can't use it that way.

Comment: You'll have to write an expression parser. Even a (JavaScript) regular expression can't handle this reliably.

Comment: Before you use `eval()` please read the section "Do not ever use eval!" of [MDN JavaScript Eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: @HerrDerb thanks for the heads up. I am new to javascript and have already gone through that question. But I don't find any other way of evaluating dynamic expressions having dynamic variables, like 'E_LOW' as mentioned afore. An alternative suggestion to this will be helpful.

Comment: You could use an already existing math library to solve this problem like: http://mathjs.org/ .
This way you are save and don't even need to tests stuff.

Comment: @HerrDerb could you please post a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the string with calculation and replace the sign `%` with `/100`. Then evaluate.

```js
var E_LOW = 10,
    calculation = 'E_LOW%',
    replaced = calculation.replace(/([a-z_]+)%/gi, '($1/100)'),
    result = eval(replaced);

console.log(replaced);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Done blind, though, odds seem high to me that it will go wrong via operator precedence, but I don't immediately have an example to point out.

Comment: by assuming only `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` it has the right operator precedence.

Comment: I thought of this as well but in my case it will be a tedious task and also unreliable. But thanks for answering.

Comment: That's a **big** assumption.

Comment: i added some parenthesis.

Comment: The only example I can come up with uses the exponentiation operator: `N%**2` would have to be `(N/100)**2` to be calculated correctly.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Re the parens: Yeah, but then you have the problem that `%` may follow something other than a simple identifier. That's why I commented on the question that a proper expression parser is needed.